Getting the actual CFM and kW from AC current
I have this AHU with a 3-phase induction motor which is connected to a VFD. I get continuous frequency data from the VFD and I would like to know the CFM  output and energy consumption in kW at each minute.
I'm not sure how to extract those in a meaningful way without an actual measurement.
I tried to do so using the fan laws and some rated data from the engine data sheet, but I fear this doesn't take slip into account which may also affect the values I receive.
The current calculation I use which doesn't account for slip is
$$Hz_{sys}/Hz_{rated}\approx RPM_{sys}/RPM_{rated}=CFM_{sys}/CFM_{rated}$$
$$CFM_{sys}\approx (Hz_{sys}/Hz_{rated})*CFM_{rated}$$
and also
$$(RPM_{sys}/RPM_{rated})^3=kw_{sys}/kw_{rated} $$
getting:
$$kw_{sys}\approx (Hz_{sys}/Hz_{rated})^3*kw_{rated}$$
I'm wondering how accurate this estimation is and if there is maybe a quick fix.(maybe using the rated slip rating) to make this more accurate.
I'd appreciate any help.

CFM is dependent on the total system, a motor doesn't give you this.  You need amps and volts to get KW.

I was trying to get an estimate not an exact number and from the AHU  rated cfm and the fan laws  i assumed the input frequency is linear to the RPM which is linear to the frequency how off is this claim ?

motor RPM comes directly from frequency.  But the motor doesn't know what impeller is attached to it, nor how restrictive the flow is.  Trying to push air through a drinking straw would be quite different from no ductwork attached.

How is the frequency of your VFD controlled?  Is it set by some air demand?  Do you have access to the measured value going into the controller?  Do you have a delta-P between the inlet and outlet?

@TigerGuy, Minor addition, synchronous motor RPM comes from frequency.  Due to slip, actual RPM comes from frequency and load.  The higher the load, the more slip with more current being drawn.  (Excuse my being pedantic.  I agree, I don't see enough info here to effectively calculate what the OP was asking.)

Hey OP here, what i was getting at is actually how accurate is it to extrapolate the CFM and energy using the formulas i gave in the edit above ( given that all the rated quantities are known and the current Hz) I'm aware that the slip makes the transition from Hz to RPM wrong but it is mostly a difference of 5% so i wanted to know maybe what's the error of this estimation and if there is  a simple fix ( maybe using the rated slip ? ) to make it better
